# Minimal column sum (?) solution to system of linear equations over $\mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic

There are $n$ equations in $n$ unknowns where  both the coefficients and unknowns come from the field $\mathbb{Z}_2$. I can represent these as the equation $Ax = b$ where $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix and $x$ and $b$ are both vectors of $n$ elements.

I can apply Gaussian elimination and find $\textit{a}$ solution, but what I am looking for is the solution vector $x$ having the minimal column sum (i.e. minimal number of 1's).

I don't know if this is relevant, but $A$ is often not of full rank.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're looking for. A matrix such that you have a minimal column sum? In that case, pick a matrix with linearly independent columns so then your solution vector is $\mathbf{0}$.

Comment: Given an arbitrary system of linear equations mod 2, I am seeking the solution vector $x$ such that $x$ has the minimal number of 1's. The matrix is fixed, I can only choose which solution to use.